# Convert array of arrays into multidimensional array in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to convert an array of arrays that is requested from a http service. I have the following code below:

This is the array from the http service that will have a number of arrays:

[object Array] >
[0] >
MAKE: "toshiba",
MODEL: "h2000"
..[n]

This needs to be converted to a multidimensional array like this:

[{MAKE:"toshiba"},{MODEL:"h2000"}, {MAKE:"HP"},{MODEL:""}];

I have looked into a for loop to do this but having no luck:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a method that converts an object to an array

```
function objToArray(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(arr, key) {
        arr.push({ [key] : obj[key] });
        return arr;
    }, []);
}
```

And then run your array through it:

```
var formattedArray = arr.map(x => objToArray(x));
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/41d3p6zx/